# Dynamic file stream handling in C with freopen

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, freopen

I am trying to write a program that ideally accepts arguments that specify both a source file (to read from) and a destination file (to write to).

The program replaces specified characters in source file, with other specified characters, then writes the output to the destination file.

There are 3 special cases I want to handle, though:

1. Only a source file to read from is provided.

   Desired Behavior: Display the result of replacing the text to the standard output (terminal)
2. Only a destination file to write to is provided.

   Desired Behavior: Read from standard input, replacing desired letters and writing result to destination file name provided.
3. Neither the source file nor the destination file are provided.

   Desired Behavior: Read from the standard in, replace characters, write to standard out.

I believe the way to do this is using `freopen()`, but I cannot wrap my head around the logic of when the file gets opened or how `freopen()` 3rd argument (stream) works.

What is the traditional way of handling this problem? Is `freopen()` even the function I am looking for to do this? Or is there some great lesser known function made for situations like these?

Some pseudo code would be really appreciated.

Comment: Create two `FILE *` variables, which you can name `In` and `Out`. If the user provides an input file name, open it with `fopen` and set `In` to the return value from `fopen`. If they do not, set `In` equal to `stdin`. If the user provides an output file name, open it with `fopen` and set `Out` to the return value from `fopen`. If they do not, set `Out` equal to `stdout`. Read from `In` and write to `Out`.

Comment: You can do it with `freopen()`. The third argument would be either `stdin` or `stdout`, depending on whether you're providing theinput file or the output file.

Comment: What would I pass as parameters to ```freeopen()``` if no file is provided? For example: no source file is provided: ```freeopen("createdSrc.txt", "r", stdin)```?

Answer (score 0):

The third argument is which of the standard file streams you want to replace with a file.

So the logic will be something like:

```
const char *input_file = NULL;
const char *output_file = NULL;

// parse arguments, setting the above variables to the appropriate arguments if supplied

if (input_file) {
    freopen(input_file, "r", stdin);
}

if (output_file) {
    freopen(output_file, "w", stdout);
}
```

Then the rest of the program uses `stdin` and `stdout` normally.

Comment: Okay, so in the case of there being an output file but no input file, we use stdin to capture the input then write it to a destination file. Would that look like this?```freopen(input_file, "r", stdin);
     fopen(output_file, "w"); ``` ?

Comment: No. When there's no input file, the `if` statement will just skip over the `freopen()`. So stdin will stay connected to its default value.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional (unixoid) way is to use only `stdin` and `stdout`.

If you want to provide an input file, use input redirection:

```
your_program < input_file
```

If you want to provide an output file, use output redirection:

```
your_program > output_file
```

If you want to provide an input file and an output file, use both ways of redirection:

```
your_program < input_file > output_file
```

And you could even add your program to a chain of commands, using pipes:

```
run_before | your_program | run_after
```

This gives you a maximum of flexibility.

It is still possible to provide options to your program.