# Using stdin and stdout if no file is given in C

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, file-handling

I have a program that copies a source file to a destination file.

In the event that only 1 or neither of these files are provided by the user, I'd like to use stdin or stdout.

For example: The source file name is not provided in command line arguments, but the destination file is. The program should read input from stdin and write to the given destination file.

I know of `freopen()` but I don't know how I should use it in this case.

Below is my boilerplate code for how I think the logic is done, but I can't find any examples of this that are helpful for me to learn. Any insight is appreciated.

```
char *src = NULL; (unless user provides in preceding code not shown)
char *dest = NULL; (^^)
        // open files based on availability

        // src and dest not provided, read from stdin and write to stdout
        if (src == NULL && dest == NULL) {
            FILE *in = freopen(src, "r", stdin);
            FILE *out = freopen(dest, "w", stdout);

            // TODO

            fclose(in);
            fclose(out);

            // src not provided, read from stdin
        } else if (src == NULL) {
            FILE *in = freopen(src, "r", stdin);

            // TODO

            fclose(in);

            // dest not provided, write result to stdout
        } else {
            FILE *out = freopen(dest, "w", stdout);

            // TODO

            fclose(out);
        }
```

Comment: Why so complicated? See my [answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996175/11294831)...

Comment: Unfortunately the way my program accepts command-line arguments is fixed (as per my professor's instruction). I have to handle files being passed with options -i for input file  and -o for output file. One or neither may be provided in test cases

Comment: @Kapernski: would you consider accepting one of the answers?

Comment: hi, yes. Apologies, I've been away for a while. I'll accept now. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to avoid `freopen` and use a different approach. I define two `FILE *` variables and either use `fopen()` if the filename is provided or set them to `stdin` or `stdout` as appropriate if not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* copying files: 0, 1 or 2 arguments */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *in = stdin;
    FILE *out = stdout;
    char *srcfile = NULL;
    char *destfile = NULL;
    int c;

    if (argc > 1) {
        srcfile = argv[1];
        if (argc > 2)
            destfile = argv[2];
    }
    if (srcfile && strcmp(srcfile, "-")) {
        if ((in = fopen(srcfile, "r")) == NULL) {
            perror(srcfile);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (destfile && strcmp(destfile, "-")) {
        if ((out = fopen(destfile, "w")) == NULL) {
            perror(destfile);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF) {
        putc(c, out);
    }
    if (in != stdin)
        fclose(in);
    if (out != stdout)
        fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if statements that's it. Verify if the src is NULL, if so `fopen(stdin, "r")` but don't close it after or it will cause undefined behaviour (I'm talking about `stdin`).
For `stdout` you don't even have to open it so you can write in it just like that. Example:

```
int is_in = src == NULL;
FILE *in = fopen(is_in ? stdin : src, "r")

if (!is_in)
    fclose(in);
```

Comment: I meant fopen but not the first argument, updated.